# C# + MySQL DB don't work in debug

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I have a problem with the MySQL database and the .Net Freamwork.

I have two applications ASP.NET MVC and desktop that connect to the database on Azure (MySQL). 
When I run ASP.NET MVC application on the localhost and desktop application that can not connect to the database and get an exception:

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.]

But when I publish ASP.NET application in Azure where I have a database this app work perfect with database.

I think may I have blocked port 3306 on system or Internet but I can connect to the database via MySQL Workbench and there I realize queries to the database so if another program can do it then why my have problem ?

Simple Code

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=eu-cdbr-azure-west-d.cloudapp.net;database=brydz;uid=----;password=----;Allow User Variables=True");

try
{
    string nazwa="";
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Nazwa FROM GRACZE WHERE Gracz_ID='" + 1 + "'";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
        nazwa = rdr.GetString(0);
```

Comment: Hmm..informations are limited and confusing..connectionstring seems different like cloudapp.net and using MySQL command to access SQL database in Azure, I mean not MSSQL? To my blurred memory, there was also some option to use MySQL in  Azure but just confused..And you need to avoid using dynamic queries to prevent SQL Injection attack..To help you, we need more clear informations..

Comment: And as just basic check, did you open the Firewall of Azure Server to specific IP address?

Comment: ConnectionStrings is the same for both applications. Azure have free MySQL for student and I used this database. I installed Connector/Net 6.9.8 and program work for local database. When I change connectionstring to remont database in Azure program don't work but when I publish ASP.NET app in Azure , it has connection with this database. I checked PoralAzure and database don't have any security for IP. I can connect with this database by MySql Workbench in my computer.

Comment: As a quick glance while I'm working, I needed to open Firewall of Azure Server to specific IP address manually. But, maybe another problem since you can connect through MySQL workbench..However, I can't understand the meaning of 'you don't have any security for IP.'